# Bucket name format in AWS Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to a bucket but keep getting either NoSuchBucket or PermanentRedirect "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint". I'm pretty sure I have set everything up correctly, I am just not specifying the bucket name right; all of the examples I have seen don't put in an actual bucket name. So if my bucket is called `example.bucket` and is in EU West 1 region, what would the bucket name be?

```
File file = getFile();
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    getApplicationContext(),
    "policy_id",
    region
);
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
    "example.bucket", // This is what I can't get right
    "test_key",
    file
);
```

Comment: you have to provide correct end point. It's changes base on region name.
check this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: Add your code and your bucket information please.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I have tried multiple variations on the enpoints provided there to no avail.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File file = getFile();
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
getApplicationContext(),
"policy_id",
region
);
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());

// add this line
s3.setEndpoint("s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"); //it changes based on region name

TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
"example.bucket", // This is what I can't get right
"test_key",
file
);
```